# SQL - All appointments to current day

Tags: sql

I have following query and I get followig error:

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

I want that dodate is less than date today so if i have appointments which isn't marked as "done" so query will list all of my appointments to current day.

```
select 
    dodate, regdate,header,starttime,stoptime,userid,custid,objid,infoid,aname 
from fkms.appointment 
where 
    done=0 and del=0 
    and dodate > (SELECT dodate, 
                         DATEADD(d,dodate - 2440587,'1970-01-01'), 
                         ts, 
                         DATEADD(s,ts,'19700101 01:0:00:000')
                  FROM fkms.appointment) 
    and userid='da'
```

Any tips?

Comment: It looks you're trying to compare single value with subselect returning multiple values in multiple columns here: `dodate > (SELECT dodate,.... from )` How is it supposed to work?

Comment: only one column can be used in sub select condition

Comment: Is this what you want? `where done=0 and del=0 and dodate > GetDate()` or `NOW()` or `sysdate` depends on your RDBMS .

Comment: In that case, make sure you get one row in sub-select by either setting the WHERE condition properly or limit the number of returned values to 1.

Comment: By the way, the inner select returns 4 values , not one and hence your query is illegal.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is illegal as the inner SELECT returns more than one value. Change it to:

```
select 
    dodate, regdate,header,starttime,stoptime,userid,custid,objid,infoid,aname 
  from fkms.appointment 
 where done   = 0 
   and del    = 0 
   and dodate > GETDATE()
   and userid ='da';
```

NOTE: GETDATE() is SQL-SERVER function. IN Oracle you have `NOW()` and other DBMSs similar functions. Find out which one you need.

Comment: Oracle does **not** have `now()`. It either uses the SQL standard `current_timestamp` or the Oracle specific `sysdate`.

Comment: Yeah. It is some months since I last messed up with Oracle and hence my mistake. In any case, I hope that the idea was clear.